# SEO Friendly exposed filter view Drupal 7

Tags: view, drupal-7, seo, drupal-exposed-filter

Currently url display like this
news/?tid=telecom

I need to alias 
news/telecom
using clean URL its works in all pages but in view exposed filters not worked

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried views contextual filters to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve it using contextual filter. You can use taxonomy term names with this filter by adjusting Specify validation criteria settings. please see this answer [Drupal 7 views contextual filters taxonomy name](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters-taxonomy-name)

Currently, it's my belief that the only generic way to solve this issue is either manipulating the URLs at the httpd layer, or using [hook_url_inbound_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7) and [hook_url_outbound_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7). You can read a bit more about the mentioned hooks [at this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19234/what-is-the-difference-between-implementing-hook-url-inbound-alter-and-hook-ur).

However, if I were to give this another shoot myself, I would attempt a Views specific solution instead, as this problem is common enough that it could be justified to have a module for this.

In [hook_views_pre_build](http://api.lullabot.com/hook_views_pre_build), one could take data from a url like "members/valuea/valueb", push these values into $_GET['q'], let views build it's query seeing the get arguments "in the url", then possibly remove them again in [hook_views_post_build](http://api.lullabot.com/hook_views_post_build).

I hope this will help you.